# TensorFlow c++ API crashes on session->run()

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am writing a Tensorflow c++ code to check if a sequence of images that i receive on the server falls into a "true" category or a "false" one. i have trained the model using python and generated a .pb file for the model.

Now I am loading the model into c++ and passing images from a vector that i receive from a connection to it using the following code:

```
for (int iLSP = 0; iLSP < LSPs.size(); iLSP++)
{
    Mat image1 []= {LSPs[iLSP], LSPs[iLSP], LSPs[iLSP]};
    Mat image;
    merge(image1,3,image);
    image.convertTo(image, CV_32FC1);
    image = image / 255.0;
    resize(image, image, Size(Width, Height));

    Tensor image_tensor(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({1,Width,Height,3}));
    StringPiece tmp_data = image_tensor.tensor_data();
    memcpy(const_cast<char*>(tmp_data.data()), (image.data), Height * Width * sizeof(float));

    Session *sess;
    SessionOptions options;
    TF_CHECK_OK(NewSession(options, &sess));
    GraphDef graph_def;
    TF_CHECK_OK(ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), "models/model.pb", &graph_def));
    TF_CHECK_OK(sess->Create(graph_def));

    std::vector<std::pair<string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = {{"x", image_tensor }};
    std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;                

    Status status = sess->Run(inputs, {"y_pred"}, {}, &outputs);
    if (!status.ok())
    {
        cout<<"Error: "<<status.ToString()<<endl;
    }
    auto output_mapped = outputs[0].tensor<float, 2>();
    totalFalse += output_mapped(0);
    totalTrue  += output_mapped(1);
    sess->Close();
    image.release();
}
```

The code compiles and run. The issue is after a number of connection to the server and receiving several image sequences, the code crashes without any error output or indication why it crashed (not even a segmentation fault).

Did a "cout" on each of the lines to check where the code is crashing and apparrently it happens on the following line:

```
Status status = sess->Run(inputs, {"y_pred"}, {}, &outputs);
```

Is there a why to debug what is happening inside the sess->run? as the code is not even filling the status variable to get an idea!. also is there a way to get an exception thrown form the session run? as i already mentioned this will be a server code and at least if the session->run is not working i can catch the exception while keeping the program running and not crash the full server

Comment: Could you try explicitly default constructing `outputs`, just for peace of mind? (That most likely won't fix it, though)

Comment: Any chance that `sess` is `NULL` at the point of the crash? (I would expect a segfault in that case, but who knows....) Do you have the code for `Session::Run()` that you can step into it (or add debug code) to do debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoints on `exit()`, `_exit()` and `terminate()` functions and run the code.